# Assertion failed Error (-215) with contourArea() c++ OpenCV 2.3.1

Tags: c++, opencv

I wanna filter contours of an image (webcam) by its area. I use findContours() and then convert them into closed polygons using approxPolyDP(). After that i want to filter them by its area (a function which generates another structure with the "useful" contours) with this function:

```
std::vector<vector<Point> > _filterByArea(double minArea,double maxArea,const std::vector<vector<Point> > contours){
    size_t ncontours=contours.size();
    size_t useful_contours=0;
    size_t i,j;
    double area;
    std::vector<vector<Point> > filtered_contours;


    for(i=0;i<ncontours;i++){
        area=contourArea(contours[i],false);
        if(area>minArea && area<maxArea){
            useful_contours++;
        }
    }    
    filtered_contours.resize(useful_contours);

    useful_contours=0;
    for(i=0;i<ncontours;i++){
        double area=contourArea(contours[i],false);
        size_t contour_size=contours[i].size();
        if(area>minArea && area<maxArea){
            for(j=0;j<contour_size;j++){
                    //filtered_contours[useful_contours].resize(contour_size);
                    filtered_contours.at(useful_contours).push_back(contours.at(i).at(j));
                    //filtered_contours.insert(filtered_contours.begin(),contours.at(i).begin(),contours.at(i));
            }
            useful_contours++;
        }
    }

    return filtered_contours;
```

}

But when running it it crashes with the following error:

OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (contour.checkVector(2) >= 0 && (contour.depth() == CV_32F || contour.depth() == CV_32S)) in contourArea, file /tmp/buildd/opencv-2.3.1/modules/imgproc/src/contours.cpp, line 1673
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /tmp/buildd/opencv-2.3.1/modules/imgproc/src/contours.cpp:1673: error: (-215) contour.checkVector(2) >= 0 && (contour.depth() == CV_32F || contour.depth() == CV_32S) in function contourArea

Trying differents things and codes I found that the error is in the line area=contourArea(contours[i],false);, which is pretty obvious but not than obvious for me because I tried a similar (same for()) code before (but not in a function, inside main() instead) and it worked perfectly. What I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's ok for me. I'm using OpenCV 3.3. Maybe you should your `contours` is not correct, or it was a fixed bug.